# Add addGpsStatusListener for the Fused location API

Tags: android, wear-os, android-fusedlocation

I have added:

```
implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener
```

and:

```
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
```

and:

```
@Override
public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "GPS status change: " + event);

    switch(event) {
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:                        
            break;                                          
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
            break;
    }
}
```

But the onGpsStatusChanged is not called for the Fused Location API. Is this possible?

Comment: No. I made an app for Wear, so I added a Service on the Mobile side and worked with the normal GPS API without Fused location (to get onGpsStatusChanged). Then communicated back to Wear (and on the Wear side I still used Fused location API i.e. mix of both).

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me. I am able to receive event in onGpsStatusChanged() method. In case you want to look at my code.

I am using gradle dependancy of play services below version

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
```

Implements

```
class FusedLocationProviderService extends Service implements 
        GpsStatus.Listener, 
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult> {

    public void initialize() {
         googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

         locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

         locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it in a Wear device?